# How to specify the link I want to download the file in python3

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I found several questions related to my question but none helped me.

I have to download .hdf files for a few years. This year I have at least 3 files per month.

I tried to loop in the shell, but it will take 1000 years until I can download all the files, outside that will block my band.

When I access the link I need to find only the link that I want to download. But this link has my variations (date, time, Julian day, and seconds), but it has the same start and ending times every year.

In the link below I show the site:

```
view-source:https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD09A1.005/2010.02.02/
```

Where it varies:

```
https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD09A1.005/ year . month . day/
```

Below I show the link that I need to get.

```
MOD09A1.A2010033.h13v12.005.2010042232737.hdf
```

However, this file name varies greatly.

```
MOD09A1. varies .h13v12.005. varies .hdf
```

One of my problems is in how do I make python find just what does not vary and fill in what varies. Another is how to download a .hdf file. And finally how do I log in and password (it is necessary to download the file). I'm new to python and I believe I have to do this, but if I do not I'll have to unfortunately use the hand to download all.

My script is:

```
import requests
import wget
import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

url = 'https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD09A1.005/2013.08.21/'


resp = requests.get(url)
html = resp.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
tags = soup.find_all('a')
t = tags[471] # where is the name I want
down = t.attrs['href']
full_path = url + down

r = requests.post(full_path, auth=('lucas', 'xxxx'), verify=True)
r.status_code
with open(full_path, 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in r.iter_content():
        fd.write(chunk)
```

But still to make my r.status_code still 401, and is not connecting and you are not downloading .hdf.
Thanks!

Comment: This question is too broad, you should ask 3 different questions for your 3 different problems.